# Assign higher z-index to mask images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, z-index

We are Fetching mask image from JSON & displaying inside Container

[image]

Onclick Mask image, we are allowing to upload another image on mask as below, also user can **drag** the uploaded image as in [Codepen1](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/EBGYWz), everything was fine...

[image]

Now Client want to display mask image above Box image, so I displayed mask image on top of box image as below :

**Issue** :

[image]

when I click on mask image [left side], higher z-index value assign to box image, so box image will override mask image.  because mask image & box image are **overlapped** with each other.

when I click on mask image [right side], then there is no problem...

Also, I can able to drag the uploaded image successfully from the right side of mask image but not from the left side.

**Z-index code** :

```
 container.enable = function() {
        draggable = true;
        $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
        div.css({
            "z-index": 2
        });
    }

    container.disable = function() {
        draggable = false;
        $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
        div.css({
            "z-index": 1
        });
    }

container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };
```

**Snippet** :

```js
var target;
const imageUrl = "";

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "name": "design3",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 300,
        "height": 300,
        "layers":[  
            {  
               "type":"image",
               "src":"14IVyVb.png",
               "name":"bg_img",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":200
            },
            {  
               "type":"image",
               "src":"l8vA9bB.png",
               "name":"mask_image",
               "x":100,
               "y":15,
               "width":180,
               "height":166            
        }]
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');
let mask;

$(function() {

    // Upload image onclick mask image 

    containerElement.click(function(e) {
        // filtering out non-canvas clicks
        if (e.target.tagName !== 'CANVAS') return;

        // getting absolute points relative to container
        const absX = e.offsetX + e.target.parentNode.offsetLeft + e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
        const absY = e.offsetY + e.target.parentNode.offsetTop + e.currentTarget.offsetTop;

        const $canvasList = $(this).find('canvas');
        // moving all canvas parents on the same z-index
        $canvasList.parent().css({
           zIndex: 0
        });

        $canvasList.filter(function() { // filtering only applicable canvases
            const bbox = this.getBoundingClientRect();
            const canvasTop = bbox.top + window.scrollY;
            const canvasLeft = bbox.left + window.scrollX;
            return (
                absX >= canvasLeft && absX <= canvasLeft + bbox.width &&
                absY >= canvasTop && absY <= canvasTop + bbox.height)
        }).each(function() { // checking white in a click position
            const x = absX - this.parentNode.offsetLeft - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
            const y = absY - this.parentNode.offsetTop - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;
            const pixel = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255)
            {
                if (!$(e.currentTarget).data('image_set' + target))
                    $(this).parent().css({
                        zIndex: 2
                    })
                target = this.id;
                console.log(target);
                if (!$(e.currentTarget).data('image_set' + target))
                    setTimeout(fileUp.click.bind(fileUp), 20);
            }
        })
    });

    // Fetch mask images from json file - IGNORE this code 

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data) {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        // container dimensions 
        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
        //end 

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {

            //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ] 
            var ImagePosition = arr;
            //code end 

            var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1 ? imageUrl1 : undefined,

                // Fetch Mask images 
                maskImageUrl: 'http://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                // end 

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions 
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end 

                },
                id: counter
            });
            // here 

            ImagePosition.map(function(cur, index) {
                var available = cur.name.includes('mask_');

                if (!available) {
                    $('.masked-img' + index).css('pointer-events', 'none');
                }
            });

            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

            };
            counter++;
        }
        return mask;
    }
    mask = json(jsonData);
}); // end of function 

// Image code 

(function($) {
    window.JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options. 
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults. 
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position 
            y: 0, // image start position 
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);

        // Create the image properties
        settings.maskImage = new Image
        settings.image = new Image

        // set the cross-origin attributes
        settings.maskImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        settings.image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

        settings.maskImage.onload = function() {
            // once the mask is loaded, load the image
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl)
            container.drawMask()
        }

        settings.image.onload = function() {
            // once the image is loaded, render to canvas

            container.drawImage()
        }

        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }


         container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }      

        container.drawMask = function() {
            if (!settings.maskImage) return true;
            canvas.width = settings.maskImage.width;
            canvas.height = settings.maskImage.height;
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            // draw the masked image after scaling 
            if (settings.maskImage) context.drawImage(settings.maskImage, 0, 0, settings.maskImage.width, settings.maskImage.height);
            context.restore()
        };

         container.drawImage = function() {
            const img = settings.image

            settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
            settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;

            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
            context.save();
            context.translate(settings.x + img.width / 2, settings.y + img.height / 2);
            context.rotate(settings.rotate);
            context.scale(settings.scale, settings.scale);
            context.translate(-(settings.x + img.width / 2), -(settings.y + img.height / 2));
            let width = img.width,
                height = img.height;
            if (img)
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, width, height);
            context.restore();
            initImage = false;           
        }

        // change the draggable image 
  
  container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            // console.log('Draw started');
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

                $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
                container.selected(evt);
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                var img = new Image();
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

            }
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
            // console.log('Drag over');
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
                if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                    if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                        var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                        var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                        if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                            return; // position has not changed
                        settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                        settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                        prevX = evt.clientX;
                        prevY = evt.clientY;
                        //logTMatrix(settings);
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            container.drawMask();
                            container.drawImage();
                        }, 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };


        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            if (!imageUrl) return true;
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;

            initImage = true;

            settings.image.src = imageUrl; // CHANGED

            // sirpepole Add this 
            return settings.id;
        };

        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {

            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            // settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            settings.maskImage.src = imageUrl // CHANGED

            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event) 
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);

            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);

            // container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
            // Moved this to the settings.maskImage.onload
        };
        if (settings.maskImageUrl) {
            container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        }
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image 
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        div.attr('data-id', settings.id);
        // ends 
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
        background: silver;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .container img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 250px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    
    .masked-img {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none">

<div id="container" class="container">
</div>
```

Here is [Video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10jOOY9eYm0WMEXl_YeRQU2SaKt3uOo0c/view) & Code in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/3pBCrR3t) & [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/tus62zgk/1/) & [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/NZeJMo)

Comment: Not sure what you're aiming for. What are you trying to achieve by assigning higher z-index value to the box image?

Comment: @yuval.bl Thanks for reply, i want to assign higher z-index to `mask` image , so that i can `upload` the image and `drag` the `uploaded image` from both `left and right` side of mask image....

Comment: @yuval.bl if i assign higher z-index to mask image, then when i click on `left side of mask image` , then i can able to upload image properly also i can able to drag the uploaded image from left side of mask image.....

Comment: Please explain the purpose of the following code (I've removed it and everything seems fine)


`div.css({
        "z-index": 2
    });`

Comment: @yuval.bl as you suggested, i removed code `div.css({ "z-index": 2 });` , now 2 issues there : one is when we click on `right side of mask image, then box image will override mask image` , secondly we can't able to drag uploaded image from left side of mask image.....

Comment: here is video screenshot  link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/19uB-bsiEPiSBelEgm66HdKPaxrYsz7ts/view

Comment: @yuval.bl if name of image starts with other than `mask_` [ in json code ] , then i need to set lower z-index for those images ..... can you please help me for that ?

Comment: `When I click on mask image [left side], higher z-index value assign to box image, so box image will override mask image. because mask image & box image are overlapped with each other.

when I click on mask image [right side], then there is no problem...

Also, I can able to drag the uploaded image successfully from the right side of mask image but not from the left side.`

Im not sure they are the problem description or the goal you want to achieve.

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski i was telling how actually things are working.... what all i need is `keep the lowest z-index to box image`, please tell me how to do that....  i tried this : `$('.masked-img' + index).css({'pointer-events': 'none' , 'z-index':'1'});` but it didt worked....

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski please join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196300/z-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confused by the overall implementation and there are multiple lines terminated without semicolon. Anyway, the root cause is inside `container.selected()`. You don't need to implement your way to find which canvas is selected. You attach the event by using `div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {...};` and the browser will trigger the event with the correct target for you. When the event is triggered, the listener will be invoked. The target is given in the event object (namely `event.currentTarget`). That is the spirit of event listener.

The original `container.selected()` predicts which canvas is touched by using mouse pointer position. Since box image and mask image have certain area overlaped, the result may contains two canvas and z-index is applied to the wrong one.

I modify `container.selected()` as follow

```
container.selected = function(ev) {
    var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
    var item = ev.currentTarget;

    JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
        var id = $(item).attr("id");
        if (el.id == id)
            el.item.enable();
        else
            el.item.disable();
    });
};
```

Comment: can you put your link 2 source into code pan so I can test? Also please update the question otherwise the solution is not answering it

Comment: Thanks i updated code in question...... here is your code : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/oKBMRM & the [result in video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LBo243Ewh5GuC8nugMx4mwEeV20Xe0Vs/view) , when we click on box image , its overriding the mask image.....